# How to rewrite/solve this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, classical-mechanics

\begin{equation}
\sin(\theta + d\theta) = \sqrt{1 + \frac{dy}{y}}\cdot{\sin(\theta)}
\end{equation}
I think this is a non-linear and non homogeneous first order equation. I found this whilst trying to solve a problem on a maths puzzles website which I think is called the 'Baristochrone' problem. Having thought about it a while, I finally ended up getting this as the result, where $\theta$ is the angle of the mass as a function of the vertical distance of the mass from it's origin, $y$.

Does anyone know how to solve this equation? I'm really just trying to find the function $\theta$, so could the answer be simplified to avoid solving that equation?

Comment: Maybe that it is this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html

Comment: I assume the first thing to do is to rewrite the equation in a form that relates  $dy$ and $d \theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation is meaningless as it combines finite and differential quantities under nonlinear functions.

We fix that using the Taylor development and ignoring second order terms and higher, giving

$$\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)d\theta=(1+\frac{dy}{2y})\sin(\theta)$$

or

$$\cos(\theta)d\theta=\frac{\sin(\theta)dy}{2y}.$$

Now this is a separable equation that can be integrated as

$$\ln(\sin(\theta))=\frac12\ln(y)+C$$
or

$$y=C\sin^2(\theta).$$

Comment: how did you get to $1+ dy/2y$

Comment: @gebra: as said, by Taylor.

Comment: the taylor series expansion of sqrt(1 + dy/y)?

Comment: or was it binomial?

Comment: @gebra Taylor and binomial coincide on this development.